# Google Sheets API v4 in React; Not getting Grid Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets-api

I have the following function in a React component that logs out the JSON being returned from my request to the API:

```
async function getAllSheets() {
    let response;
    try {
        response = await window.gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({
            spreadsheetId: gSheetUrl.split('/')[5],
            ranges: [
                'January!A1:S40',
                'February!A1:S40',
                'March!A1:S40',
                'April!A1:S40',
                'May!A1:S40',
                'June!A1:S40',
                'July!A1:S40',
                'August!A1:S40',
                'September!A1:S40',
                'October!A1:S40',
                'November!A1:S40',
                'December!A1:S40',
            ],
            includeGridData: true,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err.message);
        return;
    }
    const range = response.result;
    if (!range || !range.valueRanges || range.valueRanges.length === 0) {
        console.warn('No values found.');
        return;
    }
    console.log(range);
    // setScheduleData(range.valueRanges);
}
```

I set this up using the [JavaScript Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) in the docs.
This is working fine, except I'm getting the same result whether I set `includeGridData` to true or false; I'm NOT getting the grid data either way.
I also tried following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get?apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%221GEU4rCZoDK-6oev5DMvBQrYK3U9RPtgH36elxRYKoMM%22%2C%22includeGridData%22%3Atrue%2C%22ranges%22%3A%5B%22January!A1%3AS40%22%2C%22February!A1%3AS40%22%5D%7D) but still no luck. However, in the 'Try it' block on the given website, I do get the grid data. What am I Doing wrong?

Here's the rest of the code in the component for reference.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

// TODO:(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
const CLIENT_ID =
    'my_client_id';
const API_KEY = 'my_key';

// Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
const DISCOVERY_DOC =
    'https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4';

// Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
// included, separated by spaces.
const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly';

let tokenClient;

export const Admin = ({ setScheduleData }) => {
    const [gSheetUrl, setGsheetUrl] = useState('');
    const [gapiInited, setGapiInited] = useState(false);
    const [gisInited, setGisInited] = useState(false);
    const [isSignedIn, setIsSigned] = useState(false);

    /**
     * Callback after api.js is loaded.
     */
    function gapiLoaded() {
        window.gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
    }

    /**
     * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
     * discovery doc to initialize the API.
     */
    async function initializeGapiClient() {
        await window.gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: API_KEY,
            discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
        });
        setGapiInited(true);
    }

    /**
     * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
     */
    function gisLoaded() {
        tokenClient = window.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            scope: SCOPES,
            callback: '', // defined later
        });
        setGisInited(true);
    }

    /**
     *  Sign in the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleAuthClick() {
        tokenClient.callback = async resp => {
            if (resp.error !== undefined) {
                throw resp;
            }
            setIsSigned(true);
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            await getAllSheets();
        };

        if (window.gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
            // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
            // when establishing a new session.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: 'consent' });
        } else {
            // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: '' });
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Sign out the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleSignoutClick() {
        const token = window.gapi.client.getToken();
        if (token !== null) {
            window.google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
            window.gapi.client.setToken('');
            setGapiInited(false);
            setGisInited(false);
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }

    async function getAllSheets() {
        let response;
        try {
            response = await window.gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({
                spreadsheetId: gSheetUrl.split('/')[5],
                ranges: [
                    'January!A1:S40',
                    'February!A1:S40',
                    'March!A1:S40',
                    'April!A1:S40',
                    'May!A1:S40',
                    'June!A1:S40',
                    'July!A1:S40',
                    'August!A1:S40',
                    'September!A1:S40',
                    'October!A1:S40',
                    'November!A1:S40',
                    'December!A1:S40',
                ],
                includeGridData: true,
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err.message);
            return;
        }
        const range = response.result;
        if (!range || !range.valueRanges || range.valueRanges.length === 0) {
            console.warn('No values found.');
            return;
        }
        console.log(range);
        // setScheduleData(range.valueRanges);
    }

    const handleSubmit = ev => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        gapiLoaded();
        gisLoaded();
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ padding: '1rem' }}>
            {!gapiInited && !gisInited && (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <label htmlFor='gSheetUrl'>Enter Google Sheet URL </label>
                    <input
                        type='url'
                        name='gSheetUrl'
                        onChange={ev => setGsheetUrl(ev.target.value)}
                    />
                    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
                </form>
            )}
            {gapiInited && gisInited && (
                <div id='authorize_button'>
                    <p>Authorize Access to Google Sheets</p>
                    <button onClick={handleAuthClick}>Authorize</button>
                </div>
            )}
            {isSignedIn && (
                <button id='signout_button' onClick={handleSignoutClick}>
                    Sign Out
                </button>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: In your script, I think that if the value of `spreadsheetId`, `ranges`, and your client are valid values and `getAllSheets()` is run, `console.log(range)` shows the retrieved values. So, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? For example, in your script, `console.warn(err.message);` shows undefined if an error occurs. When it is modified to `console.warn(err.body)`, is an error shown?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. I don't get an error at all. This script runs as expected when `includeGridData` is set to `false`. I get all the cell values without any grid data such as the background color of the cells. 
The problem is when I set `includeGridData` to `true`, I get the same results back: cell values with no grid data.
However, when I use the [API demo](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) in the docs, I do get the grid data when `includeGridData` is set to `true`, as expected.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although, unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand the reason for your current issue. But, when I found it, I would like to tell it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although, unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand the reason for your current issue. But, when I found it, I would like to tell it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Tanaike hopefully one of us (or anyone) figures it out soon :)

Comment: When I read this again, I noticed that the parameter of `includeGridData` is not used in "Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet". This is used for "Method: spreadsheets.get". So, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

From your following reply,

> I don't get an error at all. This script runs as expected when includeGridData is set to false. I get all the cell values without any grid data such as the background color of the cells. The problem is when I set includeGridData to true, I get the same results back: cell values with no grid data. However, when I use the API demo in the docs, I do get the grid data when includeGridData is set to true, as expected.

When I read this again, I noticed that the parameter of `includeGridData` is not used in "Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet". This is used for "Method: spreadsheets.get".

From this situation, I guessed that the reason for your current issue might be due to `window.gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet`. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
response = await window.gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({
```

#### To:

```
response = await window.gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.get({
```

When `getAllSheets()` is modified, it becomes as follows.

```js
async function getAllSheets() {
  let response;
  try {
    response = await window.gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.get({ // <--- Modified
      spreadsheetId: gSheetUrl.split('/')[5],
      ranges: [
        'January!A1:S40',
        'February!A1:S40',
        'March!A1:S40',
        'April!A1:S40',
        'May!A1:S40',
        'June!A1:S40',
        'July!A1:S40',
        'August!A1:S40',
        'September!A1:S40',
        'October!A1:S40',
        'November!A1:S40',
        'December!A1:S40',
      ],
      includeGridData: true,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err.body); // <--- Modified
    return;
  }
  // I modified below script.
  const range = response.result;
  console.log(range);
}
```

- By this modification, when `includeGridData: true` is included in the query parameter, the grid data is returned.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)
- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)